# @JsonDeserialize does not work on interface

Tags: java, enums, jackson, deserialization

I have an interface for some of my enums with @JsonFormat and @JsonDeserialize:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonEnumDeserializer.class)
public interface JsonEnum {
    @JsonProperty("symbol")
    String getSymbol();

    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name();
}
```

And I use it for my enums like this:

```
public enum MyEnum implements JsonEnum {
    VALUE1("v1"), VALUE2("v2"), VALUE3("v3");
    private final String symbol;
}
```

When I serialize `MyEnum` I get the correct Object. But when I want to deserialize an object to `MyEnum` my custom deserializer (JsonEnumDeserializer) does not gets called.

If I add @JsonDeserialize on top of `MyEnum` then it works fine but I want to have generic deserializer for all of my enums that implements `JsonEnum`.